# Is there any way to remove bindings from all bound elements on a form close event?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, binding

According to this [document](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx), the following code causes a memory leak in WPF:

```cs
myDataBinding = new Binding("Children.Count");
myDataBinding.Source = myGrid; 
myDataBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
MyTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myDataBinding);
```

The same happens if we bind some value in XAML:

```xml
<TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" 
           Text="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path=Children.Count}" />
```

To avoid binding memory leaks we need to remove binding on the form close event like this:

```cs
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(MyTextBlock, TextBlock.TextProperty);
```

**Question**:

**Is there a way to remove bindings from all bound elements on form and child controls?**

It seems I would need some recursive method here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that the example given was very isolated and not typical in a binding situation. The referenced document outlines this...

> The TextBlock control has a binding to
>   an object (myGrid) that has a
>   reference back to the TextBlock (it is
>   one of myGrid children’s).

The problem lies in the fact that the binding is taking place across `UIElement` objects AND one of the objects is a child of the container AND the propety being binded to is not a `DependencyProperty`. Again this is not typical as most binding occurs on an object/property which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

If you have multiple bindings like this within your application then the approach should be to clear them out as needed when the given container closes as mentioned in the referenced document.

Another approach is to simply expose the data you need on your object being consumed by the View and disregard binding to the `UIElement` properties which are not of type `DependencyPrperty`. While this is not always practical it will alleviate you from the above mentioned problem.

Comment: While a good explanation, this does not actually answer the question "Is there a way to remove bindings from all bound elements on form and child controls?"

Answer (score 6):

In WPF 4 you may don't worry about leaks when binding to an object even if it is not INotifyPropertyChanged or DependencyObject. This bug was fixed.

Anyway I suppose [BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.clearallbindings.aspx) will be helpful.

Comment: Could you provide a link or reference to this bug being fixed in WPF 4?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416/en-us I found that it was fixed using my own tests

Comment: Re-targeting the test from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx) shows the issue still occurs in .Net 4.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right. It looks like they fixed one bug and added another one. We still sometimes run into memory leaks which can be solved by adding "empty" INotifyPropertyChanged or INotifyCollectionChanged implementation. That's sad.

Comment: So, is this answer correct or incorrect? The comments make it unclear. Other things I've read seem like binding to CLR properties still will cause leaks.